# Combine duplicate entries by summing and deleting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with the following information

```
Date      |      Min Worked      |      Job Number
2/4/2015           500                     123
2/4/2015           100                     123
2/4/2015           200                     321
2/5/2015           300                     321
2/5/2015           100                     123
2/5/2015           100                     123
```

I would like to combine minutes worked on any entries with the same date and job number, and delete the extras. So after running the VBA it will look like this

```
Date      |      Min Worked      |      Job Number
2/4/2015           600                     123
2/4/2015           200                     321
2/5/2015           300                     321
2/5/2015           200                     123
```

I have not had any success with code that I have tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include as much information as you can, preferably including code, about what you've tried already and what didn't work.

Comment: This sounds like the type of layout that could be summarized using PivotTables. Is there any reason you'd rather not use a PivotTable?

Comment: This must be done in VBA because it will be part of a much longer string of code. All the data is being imported from Access via VBA. This is a process that will be run daily, and I would prefer to keep as much of it automated as possible. I intend to attach this code to the end of the code that is importing the data, so that it appears in the correct format.

Comment: If it is coming from Access, why not run a query on your table that already does this? Something like `SELECT table.Date, SUM(table.MinWorked), table.JobNumber FROM table GROUP BY table.Date, table.JobNumber;` should result in what you're looking for.  Then you could import that query data into Excel and it's already deduped and summed.

Comment: Create a pivot table from the base data (on a hidden sheet if necessary) and use that aggregated data as the base for future calculations.

Answer (score 0):

tigeravatar is correct that doing that with an Access query would be the best way (easier to maintain). If you really need/want to do this in VBA though you would need to do something like:

```
Sub Condense()
    Dim i as long
    Dim ref as string
    Dim total as long 'switch to double if Min can have fractional values
    Dim o as long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Just always a good practice to use this
    i = 2 'assumes you have headers in row 1, if not use 1
    Do while Range("A" & i).value <> "" 'Assumes Dates are in column A
        If ref = Range("A" & i).value & "-" & Range("C" & i).value then
            'Match, update total
            total = total + Range("B" & i).Value

            'Remove the duplicate row. Note in this case we don't update i as what is currently the i+1 -th row becomes row i after the delete
            Range(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            'Check for macro just starting
            If o <> 0 then
                'new Date-Job combo. Output current total
                Range("B" & o).value = total
            End If 'else we're on the first time through the loop and just need to update o & ref
            'Update o & ref
            o = i
            ref = Range("A" & i).value & "-" & Range("C" & i).value
        End If
        'Update i
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```